# Grouping rows in table in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

```
First Name  Second Name Phone
A                B       1
A                B       2
C                D       3
C                D       4
```

I would like to get the required table (Every values in columns A and B that repeats will appear only in the first line of occurrence):

```
First Name  Second Name Phone
A                B       1
                         2
C                D       3
                         4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `Pivot Tables`.

Out of my head, you have to structure it like this:

**Rows**

- First Name
- Second Name
- Phone

And it will show it the way you want it. You can change the show/hide for (sub)totals to change the result a bit.

If you want the `First name` and `Second name` on the same row, you will have to edit the `Pivot Table` to use `Classic display`.

Comment: Thanks @Lars Rotgers. I would like to know if there is a way to omit the words "blank" that appears in the pivot table and if there is a way to add the headline of the source table.

Comment: You can apply a filter and unselect `blank`. I am not sure what you mean by adding the headline, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: As for the blank - I would like to replace the 'blank' words with spaces, not to hide them, is there a fast way to do it?
As for the headline in the source table I have the following header: First Name  Second Name Phone which disappears in the pivot table, why?

Comment: I see. If you go to your source table, apply a filter so you can sort, and sort on that specific column. Now you have all the blanks nicely together, you can easily replace one with a space, and copy/paste the rest.

Comment: For the headline - normally you add columns to the `value` section of the pivot table and the column headers are automatically added. Because we have everything in the `row` section, they do not show up. You could move the pivot table to `B1` for example, and copy your original column headers, so there is a brief explanation of what data is in the pivot table. If you want otherwise, you would have to write some VBA that formats your sheet to your likings.